# Eliminar último elemento del String

Tags: java, string

Tengo este código en Java:

```
for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        if(i!=0){
            r = r + "+";
        }
        if(ProblemaVagones.listaVagones.get(i).isElectricidad()){
            r = r + "x" + i;
            r.substring(0, r.length()-1);       
        }
    }
```

Mi salida de este trozo del código es esta:

```
x0+x1+x2+<=2;
```

La cual está mal porque al final tiene un "+" que sobra , he tratado de hacer un substring desde 0 hasta el penúltimo elemento de la cadena para quitarlo , por lo que se ve no funciona. Alguien ve el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del bucle comprueba si `i` está en una posición diferente a la última. Tu código quedaría así:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    if(i != 0 && i != (num - 1)){
        r = r + "+";
    }
    if(ProblemaVagones.listaVagones.get(i).isElectricidad()){
        r = r + "x" + i;     
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo acabo de probar , pero hay que quitar la línea del substring sino no pilla los index de las x , simplemente con la condición que me habías puesto ya se puede ejecutar bien

Comment: Cuando escribí mi respuesta parece ser que habías modificado tu código original, por lo que dices ahora estaría correcto.

Comment: Claro , porque con el i!=(num-1) ya no coge el último , entonces es innecsario el substring

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que recuperar el resultado del substring en un String (que puedes ser el mismo sobre el que ejecutas la operación):

```
r = r.substring(0, r.length()-1);
```

Comment: joe vaya chorrada HAHAHAH ni lo vi xD

Comment: Así no se me quita el último + , y ahora ni siquiera me pinta los índices de las "x" , que raro..

Comment: Copia el código completo actualizado para revisarlo

Comment: Solo me está fallando ahí , en esa cadena , el resto está bien

Comment: Si no vemos la modificación es difícil ver qué pasa. Por otro lado, comprueba que se cumple la condición del if de isElectricidad

Comment: x+x+x+<=2; , esa es la salida que da ahora. La condición del isElectricidad si se cumple.